# tax query between operator like

Tags: custom-field, taxonomy, meta-query, tax-query

I have a custom post called person and a taxonomy(like tags) called age. As far I have search tax query doesn't seem to support the between operator like meta query does.

Is there a way to accomplish the between, like etc operators with tax query or do I have to make my own sql question ?

Also would be better to create a custom field called age rather have a taxonomy and query with meta query that supports the compare operators ? One disadvantage I can think with using custom fields is that you can't query inside the admin panel how many people have that age or query only the people that have a certain age etc. Also if I want to find the min and max age of all people I have to get all posts and compare them one by one.

One solution I found to emulate the between operator :

```
$min_age = 18;
$max_age = 100;
$ages = array();
for($i=$min_age; $i<=max_age; $i++){

   array_push($ages , $i);

}
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'age',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $ages
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

So what do you think is better to do ?

I know my question is a bit vague and sorry for that but I would like to know what is the best solution to this kind of situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are using the custom taxonomy with a incorrect concept. You should use a custom field if you want sort by its value.

Thinking in numbers can be dificult to understand what a taxonomy is. But think in a way to group things where a group is not higher or lower than other. Every term in a taxonomy has the same value, except in hierarchical taxonomies. For example, think in animal taxonomy. All *Genus* are in the same level, all under the same parent *Family*, and all *Families* are in the same level under the same parent *Order*. How can you sort by *Genus* or search in between *Genus*?. You only can search animals if they are IN/OR/NOT IN/AND in one or more *Genus*. A taxonomy is definetely not for for values that are going to use to sort by (a searh IN BETWEEN is a type o sort by).

You could build a hierarchical taxonomy for each integer number that represent an age, but even in this case, you have to group by a taxonomy term and them recursively search for children/parent items, what is not really a sort by/search between value. I think is not practical if compared with the idea ofe age as [meta data (ie custom field)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now. Your example with animals was very clear.